# CodeIgniter file upload black hole

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload a single file in CodeIgniter 2.0.2 in a normal way.
The `do_upload()` function returns true but no file appears in the directory.
Directory permissions appear to be fine (after running other diagnostics not shown in code below), so it makes no sense that the file is not appearing in the upload directory.
Here is controller and view code, adapted straight from the CI docs.

Controller:

```
function do_upload_sql(){
    // create directory
    if (! is_dir(BACKUP_DIR)) {
        mkdir(BACKUP_DIR, 0777);
    }
    // or if it exists and has restricted file permissions, change them
    elseif(fileperms(BACKUP_DIR)!=0777){
        chmod(BACKUP_DIR, 0777);
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = BACKUP_DIR;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'backup'; // an SQL backup file type
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    //$this->upload->initialize($config);  //redundant, so commenting out
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['action'] = 'c_backup_restore/do_upload_sql';
        $tab_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['error'] = $tab_error['error'];
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('v_upload_sql', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success"; // yes it's getting here, but i get no file!
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $file_upload = $data["upload_data"];
        $this->restore_backup($file_upload); // go do something useful with the file
    }
}
```

View:

```
<p>Select the backup file</p>
<div class="not_success"><?php echo $error;?></div>
<?php echo form_open_multipart($action);?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where do you have `BACKUP_DIR` defined? Are you uploading `.backup` filetypes? `$config['allowed_types']` should probably be `sql|bkup|gz` or something to that extend if you're uploading SQL backups.

Comment: @Zenbait  I don't get any errors, but neither do I get a file uploaded to the server. That's why it's weird. `BACKUP_DIR` is defined in `application/config/constants.php`. Yes I'm uploading `.backup` files. I have tried it with `$config['allowed_types']='*'` and got the same behavior.

Comment: Hm. Turn logging on (`$config['log_threshold'] = 4` in config.php) and see what messages/errors CI dumps when you try uploading something. What does `$this->upload->data()` return? What does `$this->upload->do_upload()` return?

Comment: Ok. Turning logging on did not result in anything being printed to the browser (is there a log file I should check?). `do_upload()` returns `1`. And `data()` builds this array, which looks fine to me. `Array ( [file_name] => db_pk_v4.backup [file_type] => application/octet-stream [file_path] => C:/backup_database/ [full_path] => C:/backup_database/db_pk_v4.backup [raw_name] => db_pk_v4 [orig_name] => db_pk_v4.backup [client_name] => db_pk_v4.backup [file_ext] => .backup [file_size] => 739.05 [is_image] => [image_width] => [image_height] => [image_type] => [image_size_str] => ) `

Comment: woops, yes, checked the application/logs/ file, and there are no errors or exceptions being reported there.

Comment: Windows tends to be picky about MIME types. Add an entry to `application/config/mimes.php` for `.backup`.

Comment: checked it. `.backup` already has an entry in `mimes.php` (by previous developer on the project).

Comment: Shouldn't your file paths (BACKUP_DIR) have backslashes in stead of forward slashes?

Comment: @qwertzman it does when it's defined `define('BACKUP_DIR', 'C:\backup_database\\');` but are being changed in storage. i wondered the same thing, but i'm sure now that's not the problem.

Comment: http://www.cecilieokada.com/blog/xampp/path-problems-with-codeigniter-on-windows/ talks about CI and Windows paths. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug using the [xDebug profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).
It turned out that the native php function `chdir(path)` further downstream was the problem.
@qwertzman's link to [paths in CI](http://www.cecilieokada.com/blog/xampp/path-problems-with-codeigniter-on-windows/) may prove to be helpful to determining exactly why the hangup occurs.